# Can't access AJAX controllers from cart page

Tags: controllers, ajax

Followed this tutorial: http://www.atwix.com/magento/ajax-requests-in-magento/

Though dated, people seem to be using it just fine. I'm using Magento CE 1.9.0.1.

**After creating app/code/local/MichaelHarper/Upseller/controllers/AjaxController.php:**

```
<?php

// Filename app/code/local/MichaelHarper/Upseller/controllers/AjaxController.php

class MichaelHarper_Upseller_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**And app/code/local/MichaelHarper/Upseller/etc/config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <MichaelHarper_Upseller>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MichaelHarper_Upseller>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
  <global>
     <blocks>
         <upseller>
              <class>MichaelHarper_Upseller_Block</class>
         </upseller>
      </blocks>
  </global>
    <routers>
      <upseller>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>MichaelHarper_Upseller</module>
          <frontName>upseller</frontName>
        </args>
      </upseller>
    </routers>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <upseller>
          <file>ajaxlayout.xml</file>
        </upseller>
      </updates>
    </layout>

  </frontend>
</config>
```

I'm able to go to my local site with controller namespace without error and it loads my theme's header and footer (blank body): http://localstore.dev/upseller/ajax/index

**I then create app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/layout/ajaxlayout.xml:**

```
<upseller_ajax_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="upseller/ajaxblock" name="root" template="upseller/default.phtml" />
    </reference>
</upseller_ajax_index>
```

**And finally my template file app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/upseller/default.phtml:**

```
<?php 
// app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/upseller/default.phtml
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

Not getting anything when I load my site URL with namespace - still empty body. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Also, once I can get my Hello World working I have these two provided methods for calling this AJAX controller:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","upseller/ajax/index/someval/"+value,true);
```

-or-

```
jQuery.post(“upseller/ajax/index”, {someval: value}, function(data){...});
```

But testing them in the console renders errors.

Comment: where  your block class?]

Comment: Just added it into the config.xml file. Wasn't detailed in the tutorial. Also, the post keeps dropping the last two lines of my config.xml file where are: </frontend>
    </config>

Comment: What changes should I make to the ajaxlayout.xml file now that I've defined a block class?

Comment: block referece name is missing .it shoul <upseller_ajax_index>
<reference name="content">
     <block type="upseller/ajaxblock" name="root" template="upseller/default.phtml" />
</reference>
</upseller_ajax_index>

Comment: Thank you. Added. Refreshed but still nothing in the body. Is there another way to test/debug this?

Comment: Your `<frontend>` tag seems to have `<global>` nested inside.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the layout update handle is created from the node name, in your case `upseller`, therefore I would try `upseller_ajax_index`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Changed it to <block type="upseller/ajaxblock" name="root" template="upseller/default.phtml" />
</upseller_ajax_index> but still rendering blank page.

Comment: You should check `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:289` which is the correct layout handle. If the handle is correct, check whether your block is loaded, t hen check the template

Answer (score 1):

try by adding output attribute:

```
   <block type="upseller/ajaxblock" name="root" output="toHtml"  template="upseller/default.phtml" />
```

Comment: Still blank. I turned on template hints but it doesn't reveal anything. What would be the correct parent path for "upseller/default.phtml"? Maybe I'm not pointing at the right directory.

Comment: is your module active?

Comment: Set to true. Good thing to check though.

Comment: do u still get the blank page?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It was set to true. I'm considering closing this question. Maybe there is something wrong with my install or a conflict that isn't obvious.

Comment: did u checked the log files?

Answer (score 1):

If you aim is to simply show your block on the ajax request and no other content such as header and footer then your layout.xml should be as follows.

```
<upseller_ajax_index>
    <block type="upseller/ajaxblock" name="root" output="toHtml" template="upseller/default.phtml" />
</upseller_ajax_index>
```

The key part there is the `output="toHtml"` which will actually get your block to show.

A great example of ajax work with layout is the one page checkout. I would suggest looking into the file `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml` for any more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<upseller_ajax_index>
   <reference name="content">
     <block type="upseller/ajaxblock" name="upseller.ajaxblock" template="upseller/default.phtml" />
   </reference>
</upseller_ajax_index>
```

Please be more consistence with your module and file name

Comment: Still blank. I turned on template hints but it doesn't reveal anything. What would be the correct parent path for "upseller/default.phtml"? Maybe I'm not pointing at the right file?